# Ubuntu Server LTS 22.04.4 has internet connection, but is not visible on router's device list

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet, hostname

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS on an old mini-pc I got from work. I want to run a network share, a vpn and some other services on it and in order to get them working reliably I need to set a static IP through the router. When I open the device list on my router, my server does not show up. Neither the hostname nor the ip-address. I use DHCP, settings are all default, nothing fancy. I can ssh into the server, I can ping it and ping from it and I can install/download programs/files, which means I am definitely connected to the internet. I tried disabling the firewall, nothing changed. The router is the TP-Link Archer VR2100v with the latest firmware installed and pretty much stock settings.

ifconfig gives the following output:

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a02:3100:5aee:7901:baae:edff:fee9:ccba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::baae:edff:fee9:ccba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:ae:ed:e9:cc:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1400  bytes 335429 (335.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 725  bytes 89421 (89.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xaa000000-aa020000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 90  bytes 7105 (7.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90  bytes 7105 (7.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

route command gives following output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s25
one.one.one.one _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp0s25
one.one.one.one _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s25
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp0s25
```

ip a gives this output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ae:ed:e9:cc:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.102/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s25
       valid_lft 84918sec preferred_lft 84918sec
    inet6 2a02:3100:5aee:7901:baae:edff:fee9:ccba/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 297sec preferred_lft 117sec
    inet6 fe80::baae:edff:fee9:ccba/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

As I am not very experienced with networking, I don't know what other info I should provide, so if you need anything, just let me know and I'll add it.
Before I tried using this mini pc, I had ubuntu server on my raspberry pi4 and I did not have such problems. I also didnt have this problem when I had Linux Mint installed (with a desktop).

I appreciate any help and hopefully I can provide anything needed for troubleshooting.